# I want to add a row if not found, update if it is found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

The following code that is inserting new rows correctly if `people` isn't found. If `people` is found I want it to update existing row and also the `import_id` but the update isn't working. So basically if a new import contains the same data in `people` I want to just update `import_id`.
`people` has `name age`.

```
    Person.transaction do
      people.flatten.each do |people|
        Person.create_with({ import_id: import.id, **people }).find_or_create_by(**people)
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

To restate the requirements, if an item in `people` matches a `Person` by `name` and `age`, update that person's `import_id`. If that item in `people` does not match `Person` by `name` and `age`, create a new `Person` and set the `import_id`.

This should do what you're looking for.

```rb
Person.transaction do
  people = [{ name: 'Tom', age: 20 }, { name: 'Jerry', age: 20 }]
  people.flatten.each do |person|
    Person.find_or_create_by(name: person[:name], age: person[:age])
      .update_attributes(import_id: import.id)
  end
end
```

Find or create the person by the desired attributes, and then update the `import_id` on the new or existing record.

[find_or_create_by docs](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by)

Comment: Actually, with some testing I've found an issue. Seems like a new Person needs import_id (required) so I am guessing the find_or_create attributes (name, age) also need import_id which will break the update as import_id will never be found.

Comment: @icantcode I see. In that case, remove the `!`. The `Person` will be invalid while it doesn't have an import ID, and will be come valid when it is updated with `update_attributes`. I have updated the example.